# Incorporate fields from MegaProtoUser into a wizard screen

Tags: scala, mongodb, lift

I'm just starting out with scala and lift and am a bit stuck regarding incorporating form fields from MegaProtoUser into a wizard screen.

I have the following MegaProtoUser code:

```
object User extends User 
  with MongoMetaRecord[User]
  with MetaMegaProtoUser[User] {
    override def skipEmailValidation = true
  }

class User private () extends MongoRecord[User]
  with MegaProtoUser[User] {
    def meta = User

     //protected methods ...

}
```

And my wizard setup looks like the following:

```
object SignupWizard extends Wizard {
  object completeInfo extends WizardVar(false)

  val person = new Screen {

    //Incoroporate MegaProtoUser fields here ...

    override def nextScreen = {
       business
    }
  }

  val business = new Screen {
    val business = field("Business name","")
  }

  def finish() {
    S.notice("Thank you for registering!")
    completeInfo.set(true)
  }

}
```

I want to incorporate some selected (not all) fields from my MegaProtoUser class into the person screen but do not now how to do this with the methods available to both. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AbstractScreen`'s [`addFields`](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4/net/liftweb/http/AbstractScreen.html#addFields%28%28%29%20%E2%87%92%20FieldContainer%29%3aUnit) method can add individual fields, as well as adding all the fields from a `Record` object. This works on both [`LiftScreen`](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4/#net.liftweb.http.LiftScreen) and [`Wizard`'s `Screen`](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4/#net.liftweb.wizard.Wizard%24Screen).

```
// assuming you just want to create a new user
object user extends WizardVar(User.createRecord)

val person = new Screen {
  // addFields(() => user.is) would add all fields
  addFields(() => user.is.email)
  addFields(() => user.is.password)
  addFields(() => user.is.timezone)

  override def nextScreen = {
     business
  }
}
```

Comment: I get the impression your solution works for a ListScreen but not a wizard - I will try an implementation with LiftScreen.

Comment: Wizard's Screen also has an `addFields` method. Should work just fine.

Comment: Yeah, the method is defined on `AbstractScreen`, a superclass of both `Wizard` `Screen` and `LiftScreen`.

Comment: hmm odd, I couldn't access ScreenVar within Wizard. Probably doing something stupid..

Comment: Nah; it's me, not you. I use `LiftScreen` much more often than `Wizard`. Replaced the `ScreenVar` with a `WizardVar`.